# Table A drops rows in table B in SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which I need joined. I have two select statements with the same columns except `OrderValue` and `SalesTarget`:

```
SELECT  
    b.TrnYear, b.TrnMonth, b.Branch, b.Salesperson, b.OrderValue
FROM 
    dbo.vw_jab_Consolidated_Orders as b 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vw_jab_SalTargets as a ON a.Sequence2 = b.Salesperson
WHERE 
    b.TrnYear = '2017' 
ORDER BY 
    a.TrnMonth

SELECT 
    a.TrnYear, a.TrnMonth, a.Sequence1, a.Sequence2, a.SalesTarget
FROM 
    dbo.vw_jab_SalTargets as a  
WHERE
    a.TrnYear = '2017' AND a.SequenceType = 'BR' 
GROUP BY 
    a.TrnYear, a.TrnMonth, a.Sequence1, a.Sequence2, a.SalesTarget
```

My problem is that as there are months where there are no `OrderValues`, the `SalesTarget` value is being filtered out when I join the two tables as follows:

```
SELECT        
    a.TrnYear, SUM(a.SalesTarget) as SalesTarget, SUM(b.InvoicedSales) AS InvoicedSales 
FROM
    (SELECT        
         TrnYear, SUM(SalesTarget) AS SalesTarget
     FROM            
         dbo.vw_jab_SalTargets
     WHERE        
         (SequenceType = 'BR')
     GROUP BY 
         SequenceType, TrnYear) AS A  
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT        
         TrnYear, SUM(ActualSales) AS InvoicedSales
     FROM            
         dbo.vw_jab_Consolidated_Sales
     GROUP BY 
         TrnYear) AS b ON a.TrnYear = b.TrnYear 
WHERE 
    a.TrnYear = '2017'
GROUP BY 
    a.TrnYear
```

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT when  asking a question here.:-)

Comment: Have you tried a "left join" instead of an "inner join"?

Comment: Hi, I have tried a left join.

Comment: I've also edited the statement:

Answer (score 0):

You want a right outer join, instead of an inner join. For a right outer join, all columns of the right table are kept even if there is not a matching value in the left table.

Try this:

```
 SELECT        a.TrnYear, a.TrnMonth, SUM(a.SalesTarget) as SalesTarget, SUM(b.InvoicedSales) AS InvoicedSales 
    FROM            (SELECT        TrnYear, TrnMonth, SUM(SalesTarget) AS SalesTarget
                              FROM            dbo.vw_jab_SalTargets
                              WHERE        (SequenceType = 'BR')
                              GROUP BY SequenceType, TrnYear, TrnMonth) AS a RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                                 (SELECT        TrnYear, TrnMonth, SUM(ActualSales) AS InvoicedSales
                                   FROM            dbo.vw_jab_Consolidated_Sales
                                   GROUP BY TrnYear, TrnMonth) AS b ON a.TrnYear = b.TrnYear and a.TrnMonth=b.TrnMonth
                                   WHERE a.TrnYear = '2017'
    GROUP BY a.TrnYear, a.TrnMonth
    ORDER BY TrnMonth
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that there are values in both tables that do not exist in each table

Comment: Got it - FULL OUTER JOIN - Thanks for responding Golden Ratio and user2023861

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a RIGHT JOIN, but then if you have no InvoicedSales, you won't get any SalesTargets.  I'd use a FULL OUTER JOIN like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.TrnYear,b.TrnYear) AS TrnYear
    ,SUM(a.SalesTarget) AS SalesTarget
    ,SUM(b.InvoicedSales) AS InvoicedSales
FROM (
    SELECT TrnYear
        ,SUM(SalesTarget) AS SalesTarget
    FROM dbo.vw_jab_SalTargets
    WHERE (SequenceType = 'BR')
    GROUP BY SequenceType
        ,TrnYear
    ) AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TrnYear
        ,SUM(ActualSales) AS InvoicedSales
    FROM dbo.vw_jab_Consolidated_Sales
    GROUP BY TrnYear
    ) AS b
    ON a.TrnYear = b.TrnYear
WHERE a.TrnYear = '2017'
    OR b.TrnYear = '2017'
GROUP BY COALESCE(a.TrnYear,b.TrnYear)
```

The COALESCE() is necessary so that the column will always return the TrnYear.